# TikZ External: Figure gets cropped

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

Arrow heads from the following MWE are cropped when externalized. What am I doing wrong?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,0) -- (0,5);
     \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,0) -- (5,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong.  Arrowheads aren't taken into account when computing the bounding box of a tikzpicture.  You can explicitly enlargen the bounding box if this cropping occurs, or there may be a sneakier way to do it automatically which I'm unaware of (but would love to know about).

Comment: Is it a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71299/19356?

Comment: The newest update for TikZ CVS does now support the inclusion of arrowheads into the bounding box. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134047!

Comment: Just loading `arrows.meta` library solves the problem. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321854/1952

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is nasty, indeed. At least with pdf output (the resulting bounding box of the image is also used to clip the image). It might work better with ps output (I do not know).

I guess the only solution is to increase the size of the bounding box manually. In your example, you could use

```
\useasboundingbox (-0.2,-0.2);
```

as *last* statement (otherwise it would overwrite the entire bounding box). In our case, we simply "append" the (-0.2,-0.2) coordinate to the picture's bounding box.

---

This alters your image's bounding box, of course. That is probably what you want. If not, you might be interested in the following part of the answer.

A solution which *keeps* the current bounding box would be to rely on `trim left`, `trim right`, and `baseline` to undo the effects of `\useasboundingbox`.

Here is a possible approach:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\fboxsep=0pt
\dotfill
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[trim left=0pt,trim right=5cm,baseline]
     \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,0) -- (0,5);
     \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,0) -- (5,0);

    \useasboundingbox (-0.2,-0.2);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\dotfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

as you guessed correctly, the `\fboxsep`, `\dotfill`, and `\fbox` stuff is just syntactical sugar to verify that it works. The key idea is `trim left,trim right,baseline` combined with `\useasboundingbox`.

The first two keys allow to modify the bounding box of a picture and the third key controls vertical displacement. However, unlike the "tight" bounding box produced by the `external` lib, the resulting image has a *larger* bounding box than the trim values. The trim values are implemented by means of negative `\hspaces` and are also applied by the `external` lib. The `baseline` thing simply moves the complete image vertically; that appears to be enough.

Comment: Perhaps it's more "tikzien" to use `  \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
   (current bounding box.north east);` instead of `\fbox`.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a simple method to add some margin (2mm in this example) to your `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,fit}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,0) -- (0,5);
     \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,0) -- (5,0);

     \node[fit=(current bounding box),inner sep=2mm]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for the corpse reviving, but is there a method to add the `\node{...}` command automatically before every `\end{tikzpicture}` in the document? I haven't found anything in the tikz texdoc.

Comment: @FabianA. Try to use the `execute at end picture` key in the `every picture` style (pp.127-128, pgfmanual, v3.1.4a). Something like `\tikzset{every picture/.style={execute at end picture={\node[fit=(current bounding box),inner sep=2mm]{};}}}`.