# pgf-umlsd and externalize

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

**What would be the best solution to make [pgf-umlsd](https://code.google.com/p/pgf-umlsd/) and externalize compatible?**

The latter expects `\end{tikzpicture}` which is "hidden" within `sequencediagram` environment the first provides. I guess I could convert beginning and the ending of the environment into two commands explicitly invoked at the beginning and ending of the `tikzpicture` environment meant to be sequence diagram, but it wouldn't survive `pgf-umlsd.sty` update (i.e. changing environment definition), requiring copy-paste to be redone.

Is there any clever way to solve this problem with as minimal effort as possible and avoiding any copy-pasting?

Should the package author be convinced to provide some begin-like and end-like commands for use within `tikzpicture` environment?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[paperwidth=48mm,paperheight=36mm,margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize
% uncommenting above line gives following error:
% ! File ended while scanning use of \tikzexternal@laTeX@collect@until@end@tikzpicture.
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\begin{sequencediagram}
\newthread{a}{A}
\newinst[1]{b}{B}
\begin{call}
 {a}{call}
 {b}{return}
\end{call}
\end{sequencediagram}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above document]

---

Let's assume for a moment that author provides three macros (or: we changed [pgf-umlsd.sty](https://code.google.com/p/pgf-umlsd/source/browse/release/pgf-umlsd-0.7/pgf-umlsd.sty) ourselves):

- `\sdinit` - layers declaration, required before starting `tikzpicture`
- `\sdbegin` - sequence diagram header for use at the beginning of `tikzpicture`
- `\sdend` - sequence diagram footer for use at the end of `tikzpicture`

Modifying above listing to use them:

```
\sdinit
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sdbegin
...
\sdend
\end{tikzpicture}
```

makes `externalize` happy, but the output is different.

[image: Output of the modified document]

Right part of the rightmost box shadow disappeared. Why?
What would be the best way to fix it?

Comment: Bonus question: _Why the diagram is not in the middle of the page?_ What I have forgot about?

Comment: Crippled shadow problem is related to a bounding box not covering all TikZ drawings. See [TikZ External: Figure gets cropped](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86521/5264). In this case adding `\useasboundingbox ([shift={(0.2,0)}]current bounding box.east);` before ending `tikzpicture` environment solves the problem. (I used 0.2 because it's a value used internally in `pgf-umlsd` as the offset of the first box, thus I get external PDF with symmetrical margins.)

Comment: To your bonus question: use `\begin{figure}\centering\begin{tikzpicture/sequencediagram}...\end{tikzpicture/sequencediagram}\end{figure}`

Comment: @przemoc Self answering a question is good. Can you provide an answer, if you have solved the problem? Otherwise, please update the question.

Comment: @przemoc have you considered writing an answer?

Comment: I tested the minimal example with ` XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/TeX Live for SUSE Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)` and the problem is still there.

As a work-around, I disable the global tikzexternalization. It does not work with `\tikzset{external/export next=false}`. So I use `\tikzexternaldisable` before the sequence diagram and `\tikzexternalenable` after it.