# How can the margin around externalized pgfplots crossrefs be set?

Tags: pgfplots, cross-referencing, tikz-external, crop, bounding-box

When using `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` to externalize `ref`s to `label`s in a pgfplot, the resulting .pdf looks cropped when the linewidth used for the line corresponding to the `label` is thick (or semithick).

The effect is similar to that in [TikZ External: Figure gets cropped](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86521/tikz-external-figure-gets-cropped), except because it is a reference to a label, I have no access to the `tikzpicture` to change its bounding box in order to remove the cropping effect. How can I change the bounding box so that the resulting .pdf does not appear cropped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking inspiration from [Paul Gaborit's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86625) to the question you referenced:

Assuming that you're otherwise happy with the referenced legend entry, one way to avoid the clipping is to append an additional node to the legend image code.

The following code, inserted in your preamble, will pad `0.05em` around your legend entries. Adjust the padding to suit your needs.

```
\pgfplotsset{
    legend image code/.append code={
        \node[fit=(current bounding box),inner sep=0.05em]{};
    }
}
```

Note that you'll need to include `\usetikzlibary{fit}` in your preamble. Also, you may prefer to remove the added padding from the standard `crossref` `yshift` of `0.3em`[1] with, for example,

```
\pgfplotsset{every crossref picture/.style={baseline,yshift=0.25em}}
```

[1]: PGFPLOTS v1.8 manual p. 187