# Ignore inner sep for tikz bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box

Is there a way to have `tikz` ignore the white space produced by a `node`'s `inner sep` when calculating the picture's bounding box?

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt] (X) {X};
\draw (X) -- ++ (0.5, 0);
\draw[gray] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent X

\noindent \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=2pt] (X) {X};
\draw (X) -- ++ (0.5, 0);
\draw[gray] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

In this example, the `inner sep` is useful when drawing lines from/to the node (see the horizontal line in the example), but on the other side, it indents the second `X` with regard to the normal text. Some way of specifying the bounding box as the smallest rectangle containing all "ink" (and thereby clipping all `inner sep`s and possibly other white spaces that needlessly extend the bounding box) would be great here...

Comment: use `trim left=##pt` key to shave off the amount you like

Comment: There is also `outer sep` for a node. You have to make it 0 too.

Comment: The gray line adds also space. Also: [tikz: double lines are shifted](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130456)

Comment: @percusse: Thanks for the tip, I did not know that. However, I was looking for a (more) automated solution...

Comment: @HarishKumar, Qrrbrbirlbel: thanks for mentioning those, I did not yet think of them.

Answer (score 5):

This solution does not really ignore `inner sep` for bounding box calculation, but might give the desired result in many cases.

It seems that the value of `outer sep` does not influence the bounding box. So using `outer sep` instead and setting `inner sep = 0` does the trick.

This approach does even work partially for other shapes. In this case a negative `inner sep` (or `inner xsep` or `inner ysep`) may help with quick and dirty fine tuning.

```
\documentclass[border = 1, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep = 0, outer sep = 0.3333em] (X) {X};
        \foreach \a in {0, 5, ..., 90} \draw (X) -- ++(\a:2em);
        \fill[black, opacity = 0.25] (current bounding box.south west)
                           rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep = 0em, outer sep = 0.3333em, circle] (X) {X};
        \foreach \a in {0, 5, ..., 90} \draw (X) -- ++(\a:2em);
        \fill[black, opacity = 0.25] (current bounding box.south west)
                           rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have printed out the default value for `inner sep` for reference.

Answer (score 3):

I like krnk's answer, which was exactly what I was looking for.

The amount of code copied from Ti*k*Z can be reduced by using the shape inheritance mechanism (which may not have been available at the time of the original answer, I don't know).

I also changed the background path so that the original rectangle is created without updating the bounding box. This makes it possible to fill the rectangle white, for instance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{tight}{
    % inherit as much stuff as possible from the rectangle shape
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
    \foreach \x in {east,west} \foreach \y in {north,mid,base,south} {
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\y\space\x}
    }
    \foreach \x in {east,west,north,mid,base,south,center,text} {
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\x}
    }
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle]

    \savedanchor\tightnortheast{%
        \pgfpoint{\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox}
                 {\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox}%
    }

    \savedanchor\tightsouthwest{%
        \pgfpoint{0pt}
                 {-\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox}%
    }

    \backgroundpath{%
        % move to each of the tight corners, updating the bounding box
        \pgfpathmoveto\tightsouthwest
        \pgfpathmoveto\tightnortheast
        \pgfpathmoveto{\tightsouthwest\pgf@xa=\pgf@x\tightnortheast\pgf@x=\pgf@xa}%
        \pgfpathmoveto{\tightsouthwest\pgf@ya=\pgf@y\tightnortheast\pgf@y=\pgf@ya}%

        % draw the usual recangle border without affecting the bounding box
        \pgf@relevantforpicturesizefalse
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners\southwest
                                \northeast
        % this is executed in a grop, so bounding box tracking automatically
        % gets re-enabled if it was enabled to begin with
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \foreach \shape in {rectangle, tight} {
        \par shape = \shape:\par
        \begin{tikzpicture}[framed,tight background]
            \node[\shape] at (0,0) (x) {x};
            \node[\shape] at (1,0) (y) {y};

            \draw (x) -- (y);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image: output]