# How to eliminate gap at the start and at the end of a line when it's drawn along a side of a node's bounding box?

Tags: tikz-pgf

There are some gaps.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node(n1){text};
    \path[draw](n1.north east)--(n1.north west);
    % uncomment following line to see gaps clearly
    %\path[draw](n1.north west)--(n1.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node(n1){text};
    \path[draw,line cap=rect](n1.north east)--(n1.north west);
    % uncomment following line to see gaps clearly
    %\path[draw](n1.north west)--(n1.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What is going on here? Let's start with

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node[draw](n1){text};
    \path[fill=blue](n1.north east) circle[radius=0.1pt]
    (n1.north west)circle[radius=0.1pt];
    \path[draw,red](n1.north east)--(n1.north west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This does not have any unnecessary gap. If you uncomment

```
 \path[draw,red](n1.north east)--(n1.north west);
```

you get

[image]

So the gap is there. This is because Ti*k*Z is rather "generous" with the bounding box, here it adds the "natural extension" of the line which emerges when you do `line cap=rect`. Note that the bounding box gets much more "overestimated", see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290357/121799). AFAIK there is no built-in way to obtain the exact bounding box.

Comment: See also loopspace answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130472/2388 regarding "exact bounding box".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, but this doesn't work for Bezier curves AFAIK