# Why are the endpoint lines of intervals (`|-|`) not shown completely?

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I use `\draw[|-|] () to ();` to draw a few intervals.

I expect that each interval is rendered like `|----|` (see the 2nd and the 3rd intervals in the figure below).

However, the top and the bottom intervals below show only a half of their endpoint lines (i.e., `|`).

Why are these endpoint lines (`|`) not shown completely? How to show them?

[image: tikz-interval]

---

[<del>Editable</del> ReadOnly Code@ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/582068a97299190d58ac4d2d)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[|-|, red] (0,0) to (1,0);
  \draw[|-|, red, dashed] (0,1) to (1,1);
  \draw[|-|, blue, dashed] (0,2) to (1,2);
  \draw[|-|, blue] (0,3) to (1,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: arrowheads don't modify the bounding box of the picture and standalone thinks that's the bounding box only with the lines

Comment: @percusse: you're right unless you load `arrows.meta`. See Till's comment from 01/08/2016 in https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/77/#9229

Comment: @Ignasi Well, well somebody is back :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to change `standalone` border margins. Loading `arrows.meta` tikzlibrary, arrows tips are included in bounding box (see [How to make a smarter cropping with standalone or preview packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321854/1952)):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[|-|, red] (0,0) to (1,0);
  \draw[|-|, red, dashed] (0,1) to (1,1);
  \draw[|-|, blue, dashed] (0,2) to (1,2);
  \draw[|-|, blue] (0,3) to (1,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The real margin to be chosen:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone} % here PS
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[|-|, red] (0,0) to (1,0);
  \draw[|-|, red, dashed] (0,1) to (1,1);
  \draw[|-|, blue, dashed] (0,2) to (1,2);
  \draw[|-|, blue] (0,3) to (1,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Ignasi showed that `Loading "arrows.meta" tikzlibrary, arrows tips are included in bounding box`. I think this solution is better (because it gives the reason). Therefore, I have changed my mind and accepted it. Sorry for that. Thanks for your efforts.