# Tikz cuts off top of text in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box

I am drawing an arrow with text above it

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<-, thick, postaction={decorate, decoration={text along path,text align=center, raise=.7em, text={Process}}}]
        (0, 0) to [bend left=60] (5, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result cuts off the top of the text of the label. 
[image]

How can I fix the bounding box of the tikzpicture so that it adjusts itself the text of the label? Can I get the decorations to extend the bounding box, the way `arrows.meta` does for arrows?

---

I would like the bounding box of the tikzpicture to adjust automatically to the contents of the picture, rather than have to fine tune a fixed value.

If I put the text in its own node, it doesn't get cut off, but then it doesn't follow the path of the arrow.

Of course, I can not raise the text, but then it is too close to the arrow.

---

The accepted answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337997/63689) has nothing to do with my problem, since the `arrows.meta` package doesn't change the bounding box for decorations. The other answers to that question suggest adding margins, but I do not want to have to fine tune the margin parameter (and then have to change it again, if I move the arrow decoration).

Comment: No problem here. Maybe you have some other command to clip the images.

Comment: Without a complete example, it's difficult to answer. The answer, I think, is that you made a mistake before because your code compiles perfectly.

Comment: It compiles, but the top is cut off in the output

Comment: no your code is correct. You need to give a complete example with the document class etc .

Comment: If we try OP's code with standalone class, we get the issue about which s/he is talking. Try this `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[<-, thick, postaction={decorate, decoration={text along path,text align=center, raise=.7em, text={Process}}}]
 (0, 0) to [bend left=60] (5, 0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are the endpoint lines of intervals (\`|-|\`) not shown completely?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337948/why-are-the-endpoint-lines-of-intervals-not-shown-completely)

Comment: The arrow endpoints look nicer with `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}`, but the label is still cut off. And with `margin=1cm`, I have to change the margin value if I change the label.

Comment: Technically, standalone is cutting off the top, which extends beyond the bounding box.  The quick fix is to add a [border=10pt] or so to standalone.   Another solution is t add an invisible point above the (current bounding box).

Comment: It is a known bug: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497684.

Comment: You can cheat: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<-, thick, postaction={decorate, decoration={text along path,
text align=center, raise=.7em, text={Process}}}]
        (0, 0) to [bend left=60] node[above={0.7em-2pt}]
  (cheat) {\phantom{Process}} (5, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  I have no problem with `standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a` and the initial code. I compile with lualatex but it's correct with pdflatex too

Comment: @AlainMatthes I do reproduce the issue. More precisely, if I compile the example, the text is barely in (but not cut as badly as in the OP's screen shot). If I use `text={|\Huge|Process}`, then it gets cut more badly. The fact that it is is originally partly visible is IMHO an accident because the bounding box gets overestimated, a well known effect for Bezier curves that you wrote a nice answer for. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat ok now I see !!  But I know another bug ! now I'm old and I'm forgetting what I've been studying...

Comment: @AlainMatthes For the Bézier curve problem there is now the `bbox` library that is described in section **46 Bounding Boxes for Bézier Curves** of pgfmanual v3.1.5. I always plan to make it more stable but somehow I never have more than 20 minutes time so I keep postponing.

Comment: @usernumber By default, the standalone class cuts the image according to its size plus a border of `0pt`. This border can be enlarged. There is no other way to fix this in the manual, except to permanently change this border by modifying the `standalone.cfg` file in your local texmf so that the border added with e.g. `border={0pt 1.5pt}` is permanently changed.Thus, @Kate's solution is in my opinion the only valid one here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making the text follow a path different from that of the arrow, the text follows a bend and is not cut off by the bounding box

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xa}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xb}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{.2}

\draw[<-, thick]
        (\xa, \y) to [bend left=60] (\xb, \y);

\path [decorate,decoration={text along path, text align=center, text={Process}}] (\xa, \y + \m) to [bend left=60] (\xb, \y + \m);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

The bounding box is not calculated correctly. One can proof this by drawing the bounding box using `\draw[red] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);`

[image]

Quick hack is to add a margin to standalone class.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1cm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<-, thick, postaction={decorate, decoration={text along path,text align=center, raise=.7em, text={Process}}}]
        (0, 0) to [bend left=60] (5, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```